# How to access files of Windows using bootable Ubuntu flash drive

Tags: 14.04

I run Ubuntu 14.0 using a flash drive on my Windows 8.1-64 bit PC. Now is it possible that I can access files and folders of the Windows using that bootable flash drive having Ubuntu. If yes and please tell me how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have all mountable drives shown in the Launcher and/or in Nautilus' side bar.

Just click on the Windows drive (probably labelled *WIN* or *WINDOWS* or whatever) and it will be automatically mounted, if possible. Cases in which mounting a Windows partition is impossible include:

- If the installed Windows is hibernated rather than fully shut down, the partition will have a flag telling so. `mount.ntfs` may refuse to mount the drive.
- If the partition is encrypted, you either can't mount it or can't read from it.

There may be other cases in which a Windows drive remains unmountable, but these two are the most common problems.